# Angular PrimeNg- Callback on SideNav close

Tags: angular, primeng, angular7

I am using this primeng link- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/sidebar

I am trying to get a callback or call a method `sidenavClosed()` which should get triggered when sidebarnav gets closed either way (either by clicking outside sidebarnav or closing with close icon or any event).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-zvbmdq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so by calling the builtin `onHide` callback, in your HTML add `(onHide)="sidenavClosed()"` to the `p-sidebar` tag:

```
<p-sidebar (onHide)="sidenavClosed()" class="menuPanel" [(visible)]="opened" position="right" [showCloseIcon]="true" autoZIndex="true" baseZIndex="99999">
Sidebar1

</p-sidebar>
```